# How to map a SATA device name to a physical SATA interface for RAID systems

Tags: linux, centos, raid, mdadm, sata

I have a system with 10 SATA ports, and another SATA as the boot disk.
The 10 SATA ports make up 5 software RAID1 arrays. The RAID disks may be removed between boots, and swapped in with arbitrary blank disks at any time.

I need to ensure that `/dev/sda` is *always* my first physical SATA port, and `/dev/sdj` is *always* the tenth, for the RAID1 arrays to properly operate. If, for example, the first disk in the first port fails, that should be marked as a missing disk and so the disk in the next port should be `/dev/sdb`. Currently, the next available disk is mounted as `/dev/sda` – completely destroying my arrays and my boot configuration.

Imagine a horrible scenario where every other disk fails, so each RAID1 array has only one working disk in its pair. The numbering *should* be:

- `/dev/sda`
- `/dev/sdc`
- `/dev/sde`
- `/dev/sdg`
- `/dev/sdi`

NOT:

- `/dev/sda`
- `/dev/sdb`
- `/dev/sdc`
- `/dev/sdd`
- `/dev/sde`

I have seen `udev` rules for labelling specific disks by UUIDs, but since users will be hotswapping disks arbitrarily this is not convenient at all.

By default Linux will label the next available disk with the next alphabetical character. There are many situations where a single broken disk will break multiple RAID 1 arrays.

- How can I map a device to a specific hardware interface? Is this even possible?
- Is it possible to have a "missing" device on boot, so subsequent devices do not get labelled incorrectly ?

Comment: Why do you need the drive letters and why would rearranging the letters destroy your archive? mdadm puts a unique UUID in the partitions that belong together. And that is what you should have in you mdadm.conf. What file is referring to these partitions by name?

Comment: I may haved misunderstood how mdadm works but I am configuring my arrays using `ARRAY /dev/md1 devices=/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1` in mdadm.conf, but depending on which disks are available /dev/sda1 may correspond to a different disk than intended. I create the array with `mdadm -Cv /dev/md1 -l1 -n2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1`. I would like to know how to assign /dev/sda to a particular SATA connection on my motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Persistent_disk_names) has an excellent entry describing what I required. Following this I made my own rules under /etc/udev/rules.d/20-disk-bay.rules. I have only included the first two sata port mappings as an example:

```
# There are different DEVPATHs for major kernel versions!
# Example for SATA N:
#
# Kernel < 3 DEVPATH
# *1f.2/hostN/targetN:0:0/N:0:0:0*
#
# Kernel > 3 DEVPATH
# *1f.2/ata(N+1)/host*

########## Map SATA 0 to /dev/sdb ##############

# Kernel < 3

KERNEL=="sd?", SUBSYSTEM=="block", DEVPATH=="*1f.2/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0*", NAME="sdb", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger My disk ATTR{partition}=$ATTR{partition}, DEVPATH=$devpath, ID_PATH=$ENV{ID_PATH}, ID_SERIAL=$ENV{ID_SERIAL}", GOTO="END_20_PERSISTENT_DISK"

KERNEL=="sd?*", ATTR{partition}=="1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", DEVPATH=="*1f.2/host0/target0:0:0/0:0:0:0*", NAME="sdb%n", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger My partition parent=%p number=%n, ATTR{partition}=$ATTR{partition}"

# Kernel > 3

KERNEL=="sd?", SUBSYSTEM=="block", DEVPATH=="*1f.2/ata1/host*", NAME="sdb", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger My disk ATTR{partition}=$ATTR{partition}, DEVPATH=$devpath, ID_PATH=$ENV{ID_PATH}, ID_SERIAL=$ENV{ID_SERIAL}", GOTO="END_20_PERSISTENT_DISK"

KERNEL=="sd?*", ATTR{partition}=="1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", DEVPATH=="*1f.2/ata1/host*", NAME="sdb%n", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger My partition parent=%p number=%n, ATTR{partition}=$ATTR{partition}"

########## Map SATA 1 to /dev/sdc ##############

# Kernel < 3

KERNEL=="sd?", SUBSYSTEM=="block", DEVPATH=="*1f.2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0*", NAME="sdc", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger My disk ATTR{partition}=$ATTR{partition}, DEVPATH=$devpath, ID_PATH=$ENV{ID_PATH}, ID_SERIAL=$ENV{ID_SERIAL}", GOTO="END_20_PERSISTENT_DISK"

KERNEL=="sd?*", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", SUBSYSTEM=="block", DEVPATH=="*1f.2/host1/target1:0:0/1:0:0:0*", NAME="sdc%n", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger My partition parent=%p number=%n, ATTR{partition}=$ATTR{partition}"

# Kernel > 3

KERNEL=="sd?", SUBSYSTEM=="block", DEVPATH=="*1f.2/ata2/host*", NAME="sdc", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger My disk ATTR{partition}=$ATTR{partition}, DEVPATH=$devpath, ID_PATH=$ENV{ID_PATH}, ID_SERIAL=$ENV{ID_SERIAL}", GOTO="END_20_PERSISTENT_DISK"
KERNEL=="sd?*", ATTR{partition}=="1", SUBSYSTEM=="block", DEVPATH=="*1f.2/ata2/host*", NAME="sdc%n", RUN+="/usr/bin/logger My partition parent=%p number=%n, ATTR{partition}=$ATTR{partition}"

LABEL="END_20_PERSISTENT_DISK"
```

The rules above will always map any drive placed in SATA port 0, the first physical SATA port on my motherboard, as /dev/sdb and any drive placed in SATA 1 as /dev/sdc 
Consistent physical port mappings are critical in my use case, as I have 5 RAID-1 arrays where the disks can be arbitrarily swapped out of their physical hotswap bays. A non-technical user can swap out these disks at any time without having to deal with device IDs - the system is fully autonomous and will not construct the RAID arrays over the wrong disks in the hotswap bays.
This is a very specific use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you create an array with:

```
mdadm --create --name=DATA00 --level=6 --auto=part --verbose /dev/md0 --raid-devices=6 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sde1 /dev/sdf1 /dev/sdg1
```

and then do:

```
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
```

you get an entry in `mdadm.conf` like:

```
ARRAY /dev/md/DATA00 metadata=1.2 name=owl:DATA00 UUID=5eeada67:ff994361:bae3ab52:d9e8bd49
```

There is no need to refer to the original partitions and/or driver ordering as the UUID takes care of this. Which actual partitions constitute the array after activation/reboot can be seen from `/proc/mdstat`. To look at an individual partition (including its UUID) use `mdadm --examine /dev/sdXY`

Given that there is **never** a need to have a particular order in your drives after reboot and since my BIOS switches things around depending on whether I have an external SATA attached or not, I am very happy that it doesn't matter.

Comment: I agree that in your example drive order does not matter, however I require multiple RAID devices in a system - I have /dev/md1 -> /dev/md4. The ordering does matter in that case, a disk intended for /dev/md1 could be incorrectly used in /dev/md2.

Comment: I have found [this](https://wiki.debian.org/Persistent_disk_names) on the Debian Wiki which seems to be a solution to this issue. I will post this as an answer if it resolves my issues on CentOS.

Comment: @sg90 Why would the ordering matter? The partitions belonging to different RAID devices will have different UUIDs and that can solve which partition belongs to what drive. Why doesn't that solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why are users hot swapping disks arbitrarily?

Many hot swaps means the disks will most likely be worn faster. The raid advantage in speed will be lost. In fact, the performance of the array will probably be worse than a single disk while it's recovering.

The habit of ripping out disks arbitrarily will sooner or later land you in a situation where someone happens to pull out two disks belonging to the same array, likely crashing the system as a consequence.

Not to mention the problems you've described here. And I am not sure mdadm will pick up a new disk without it being manually added to the array, but there may be ways around that.

Is this a backup scheme? Then I highly discourage it! Use conventional backup - perhaps with LVM snapshots if you have LVM.

If users are "abusing" your servers, put a lock on the server room door... or deprive them of the keys supplied with most hot swap bays... or inform management that the system - important enough to have raid - is risking down time due to this behavior.

**Do not hot swap disks unless the disks are broken or to be replaced due to old age!**

Hot swapping is a tool to allow uninterrupted system uptime when replacing disks that are broken, old or needs to be replaced for some other, *irregular* reason - that is pretty much all it's good for (which is good enough when it comes to very important systems).

When a disk breaks you can either have an extra spare disk added to the raid array beforehand, causing the spare disk to be synced automatically, or you will have to add the hot swapped replacement disk manually.

See Anthon's answer, or this guide: https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/RAID_setup