# module scsi_wait_scan not found on CentOS kernel-ml causes kernel panic on boot

Tags: centos, rhel, linux-kernel, initramfs, scsi

I am attempting to upgrade from kernel-lt to kernel-ml, following the instructions [here](http://linuxaleph.blogspot.co.uk/2014/06/kernel-panic-scsiwaitscan-on-centos.html), however on boot the console is flooded with

```
module "scsi_wait_scan" not found
```

This leads to a general kernel panic:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000100

CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: init Not tainted 3.18.5-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 #1
Hardware name: ASUS All Series/X99-S, BIOS 1203 12/10/2014
```

This kernel is on the same bootable USB drive as described in my previous questions [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/182049/initialise-usb-devices-before-hard-disks-during-grub2-boot). Kernel-lt and the current kernel are able to boot correctly, it is only the ml which has this issue.

I have tried configuring and updating dracut, and adding a rule to load the "virtio_blk" module, but these have not fixed my issue.